TimeConstrained and optimization
I am trying to understand why wrapping TimeConstrained[] around optimization, e.g., MinValue[] can sometimes fail.
To reproduce this behaviour, use a fresh kernel and evaluate the following line:
TimeConstrained[MinValue[{x, x^2 == 1.}, x], 2]

The first time it returns -1, but on the second evaluation, it returns -∞ with the error message:

NMinimize::ubnd: The problem is unbounded.

MinValue[] does not even try. Same with NMinValue[]. Why?
I understand that if I do either of the following, the problem goes away:

remove the decimal point to make this exact
increase the time constraint significantly, e.g., to 2000 (or remove the TimeConstrained[] totally)

I am using version 14.0.0.0, Windows 64-bit.

Can't reproduce it in a fresh kernel of 14.0 on Windows 10: ClearAll["*"];
TimeConstrained[MinValue[{x, x^2 == 1.}, x], 200] // Timing returns {0.40625, -1.}.

However, its third execution returns "NMinimize::ubnd: The problem is unbounded." and {0.109375, -\[Infinity]}. Likely a bug.

Thank you very much for your input. As I want this to work for the inexact cases (i.e., not removing the decimal point), and I would like to leave TimeConstrained[] in there, with a reasonable time constraint, can you think of a workaround? Thank you again.

Please specify which version of Mathematica you are using. As @user64494, there seems to be no problem in v14.0, so it might be a bug that was already fixed.

I am using the same version as you, 14.0.0.0, Windows 64-bit. @user64494 also saw the same behavior on the third execution.

And AbortProtect[] did not help.

Hmmm, I see. I actually also got this error message now, but I can't reproduce it again ... Can you quit your kernel, and then show exactly which sequence of evaluation leads to this error message? Or does it already happen at the first try?

Indeed interesting! Thank you for this suggestion, for reproducing the results. (Although I still do not have a workaround.) This is most clearly seen with a smaller time constraint. E.g., starting fresh each time: TimeConstrained[MinValue[{x, x^2 == 1.}, x], 2] the first time is fine, but the second time -- in a new cell -- is not. In the same, initial cell, it works fine no matter how many invocations. But not once I am in a new cell. (Huh??). Thanx.

I think you should report this to the WRI as a "bug", but note that this is very likely due to internal caching and that there is a warning about this: the 7th bullet point in TimeConstrained says TimeConstrained may give different results on different occasions within a single session, for example as a result of different conditions of internal system caches. However, disabling cache via SetSystemOptions does not seem to help ...
